# TortoiseSVN checkout problem in Windows

Tags: svn, xcode, tortoisesvn, filenames

The problem is that I'm checking out some files with special characters in their filenames -- when TortoiseSVN attempts to check the code out, it can't create those files and the checkout fails. this applies to updating as well.  Is there any fix/workaround to this, maybe to give an alternate filename or something?

**Update:** Apparently, those files are created by xcode.  Does anyone know what they do?  Will it break the build if I change the filenames, like all the `>` to `-` or something?

Comment: any example of a path that fails?

Comment: Can't check path 
'D:\...\MainController.o~>': 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

That's the exact error message it gives (with part of the path omitted) and halts the update on.

Comment: There is a `>` in the file name? What platform did that get checked in on? Can you check it out there?

Comment: files with $ and > exist, checks in and out on Leopard OSX.

and they're scattered, across directories so ignoring folders won't help

Comment: There is a program that regularly creates files with `$` and `>` in the name? That should be made a punishable offense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done. As far as I know, both `global-ignore` and `svn:ignore` serve to keep files *out* of the repository only. The only solution I can think of is to check out the whole repository on OS X, make the changes, check the code, and import them back.

If the files are generated automatically by some tool, you should be able to set up `ignore` rules that prevent them from coming into the repository again, depending on what the file names look like.

**Additional idea:** You *could* try mount an OS X partition/drive to your Windows system and see whose naming rules apply. I think however, that Windows generally [forbids the use of reserved characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) in all files it handles, no matter whether the target file system would support them or not.

Comment: not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks :)

I hope xcode doesn't need them -- if that's the case, I'll just write a script to delete all of those and import, heh.

Answer (score 6):

If you have write access, you can rename the files directly in the repo by using repo browser without having to actually check out the file first.

Comment: I have write-access, but I'll need to check and make sure that changing the name won't affect anyone else or compiling (it's code in applescript).  Is there a way to have it omit those files and get everything else without having the select all the other parts manually? as in an except clause?

Comment: With some clever use, Sparse Checkouts (http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#sparse-checkouts) will let you ignore certain folders, but I don't think it is possible to ignore a file on checkout.